# How the &nbsp; works with &#10; in the placeholder attribute?

Tags: css, placeholder

A question about how the line break and space characters work together in the  placeholder attribute.
Here is my code:
`<textarea  placeholder='ex:&#10;{"data":{&#10;&nbsp;"name":"petter"&#10;}&#10;}/>`
Here is the display:
[image]

Ideally, I want it's shown as a standard JSON Format, for example it will have some space before "name"

But I don't know why `&#10;` and `&nbsp;` can't work together.
The `&nbsp;` can work very well among the letters, but not after the `&#10;`.
Any idea how to make it display properly?
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

use `&#32;` instead

```html
<textarea  placeholder='ex:&#10;{"data":{&#10;&#32;"name":"petter"&#10;}&#10;}' cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: It works well in the code snippet, however in my chrome browser, the '&#10;' doesn't work if it comes with '&#32;'. And idea?